# android modularisation - Get a call back from another module when launched through Intent

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, modularity, unauthorized, android-architecture

I am currently working on android modularisation. I have a scenario if Module A during API call (Unauthorised) launches activity in Module B(Login Module).  Can we have a call back to module A whether the Login in Module B is success so that we can try the failed request.

We can get a call back through StartActivtyForResult Intent. But when there are many API requests  it will not be possible to handle the Intent result well. It can also result in duplication of code across the app in handling intents.

Is there a way to hold the failed API call and retry after the call back from another module? Any thoughts on the approach would be helpful

Comment: You should declare module Core, module core will be declare EventBus pattern, If you using RxJava you can using PublishSubject to push event to previous Activity different module. do you use RxJava?

Comment: Thanks Cong Hai. Yes I am using Rxjava. Is the PublishSubject used to observe the login state or can it hold the api call method to retry which resulted in Login module . Need to explore what PublishSubject can provide.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create `core` module, make `module A` and `mobule B` implementation module `core`
2. In module `core` add dependencies `RxJava2` and create class `EventBus` and `Event`. If you want to push `Event` with more data just extends it.

```
object EventBus {
    private val sStream: Subject<Event> = PublishSubject.create<Event>().toSerialized()

    @JvmStatic
    fun push(event: Event) {
        sStream.onNext(event)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun observerOnUi(topic: Int): Observable<Event> {
        return sStream.filter { event: Event -> event.topic == topic }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun observerOnBackground(topic: Int): Observable<Event> {
        return sStream.filter { event: Event -> event.topic == topic }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
}
```

```
open class Event(val topic: Int)
```

3. Usage in module B you can call

```
EventBus.push(Event(REQUEST_FAILED)
```

4. Observe in module A create `CompositeDisposable` make sure you call dispose() when componenet destroy.

```
val disposable = CompositeDisposable()
disposable.add(EventBus.observerOnUi(REQUEST_FAILED).subscribe({
   // do anything
}))
```

I use Kotlin code, if you have problem when convert to Java let me know

Comment: I do use Kotlin,  Thanks for putting up the code, will try and let you know